# Qué significa "chandra" en español? Es término medieval?

Tags: traducción, historia, vocabulario-técnico, diccionarios, español-medieval

Estoy traduciendo un texto sobre [la historia del parto en la Navarra del siglo XV-XII](https://dadun.unav.edu/handle/10171/39977) para el portugués, en ella hay muchos cruces entre la historia de mujeres parteras, llamadas comadres, con registros judiciales, leyes, juntas de médicos que fiscalizaban su trabajo y hasta el poder de la iglesia para controlar el trabajo de parto que hacían las comadres, mal vistas por buena parte de los médicos, jueces y cristianos del periodo. En ese lío me encuentro yo con la palabra "chandra", como se muestra abajo:

> Así, el bautismo en caso de necesidad de una criatura pasó a ser estrechamente controlado. En efecto, en 1530, una partera, una «buena
> **chandra**», vecina de Pamplona —«**chandra** de creer» se la denomina en el Fuero General de Navarra—, fue acusada ante el tribunal de la Real
> Corte y presa, entre otras cosas, porque según varios testigos, entre ellos María Martín de Mezquíriz, puede haber ocho días poco más o menos que estaba de parto una vecina desta testigo que se llama María de Erviti, mujer de García de Azteráin. Y habiendo ido a visitarla, porque había tres días que estaba que no podía parir porque tenía muerta la criatura en el cuerpo; y estando esta testigo sentada en la dicha casa, llegó dicha María de Orzáiz, acusada [y] comenzó a decir la dicha acusada de cómo por falta de la dicha quejante, habiéndose puesto a parir con ella por su partera se había perdido la ánima de una criatura suya de la acusada porque sacó el brazo tres veces y no le dio el bautismo.

No hago ideia de lo que pueda significar eso, y me parece que no tiene nada que ver con referéncias de la cultura indiana como suelen apuntar mis búsquedas en google. Tampoco el diccionario de la Real Academia Española me presentava algo útil, lo que llega más cerca es "chanda", y tampoco me parece que sea eso. Me imagino que sea una palabra del español medieval, pero no estoy seguro, así que les pido ayuda para terminar de vez la traducción.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chandra**

**Chandra** - Hoy en día podríamos traducirlo por "mujer honrada", "buena mujer", hace unos años "mujer de su casa" o "mujer digna". En navarro y vasco igualmente tiene la consideración de "**Matrona**", también mujer laica, ama de casa respetada, afanosa y diligente que hace las funciones de Matrona.

**Chandra de creer** - A lo anterior se añade la importancia de su religiosidad. Una "mujer cristiana" y piadosa con creencias acordes a la Iglesia. Mujer hacendosa y "capitana" de la casa, igualmente tiene la consideración de "**Matrona**".

---

Durante la Edad Media los criterios de la Iglesia fueron variando a la hora del bautismo de un recién nacido, aunque siempre fue tenido por un gran problema el bautismo de los niños muertos en el parto, pues la idea primaría era que Dios el que daba el soplo de la vida y si estos no se bautizaban a tiempo, quedarían condenados para el resto en el infierno. Posteriormente aparecieron el llamado "*bautismo bajo la chimenea*" y el "*santuario de resurrección momentánea*" y a partir del S. XIV aprox. podía bendecirse solo el vientre materno, ya que los hijos de cristianos al ser concebidos cristianamente, en un vientre cristiano, no necesitaban ser bautizados, por lo que la medida fue un consuelo ante tanta angustia y desesperación, aunque esta consideración no fue general ni se dio a la vez en todas partes.

Así se constata la función importante de la matrona en la
administración del bautismo de emergencia.

La correcta administración del bautismo por parte de la matrona era considerada una competencia profesional y formaba parte de la enseñanza reglada de las matronas, pero parece que solo se constata a partir del S. XVIII en los manuales
de instrucción en 1750, en el S. XVII, existen discusiones sobre la conveniencia y forma de administrar del bautismo en casos de necesidad por parte de personas diferentes al cura o sacerdote, por lo que es posible pensar que en épocas anteriores esta "**necesidad**", no estuviera suficientemente reglada.

---

En el ámbito navarro tenemos también la influencia vasca y otras como la aragonesa y la castellana. Así encontramos que en estas tierras navarras y vascas la utilización de la voz "**etxandera**" y de cierto plurilingüismo que aparece en El Fuero en frases como "Deuen yr a la veylla o el **echayun** (amo de casa) o ela **chandra** (ama de casa).

Por otra parte la voz esta ampliamente documentada en la lengua vasca;

> **etxandre**.
>
> (Lar, Añ (-ea det.), Hb, H), etxandra (Vc ap. A), etxandera
> (V-ple-arr-ger-m ap. A), etxandere, etxeandre, etxeandra, etxeandere
> Señora de la casa; dama. "Señora de casa" Lar. "Mujer de su casa,
> señora" Lar, Añ. "Patrona de la casa y alojamiento" Ib. "Etxandra,
> dueña de casa. Se usa más para significar 'mujer retirada y
> hacendosa'"...

**A una mujer honorable, una dama o una señora.**

> Emakume honradu, **etxandera** edo señora bati.

***"Matronas"**. Otag EE 1881b 58. Un ama de casa muy respetada.*

> **"Matronas"**. Otag EE 1881b 58. Errespeto andiko etxeandre bat.

> Tr. Documentado sólo en la tradición meridional. Atestiguado ya en
> Navarra en época medieval (hay **echandra** (v. **etxejaun** ) y **chandra** en el
> **FGN** (**1234;** cf. TAV 2.2.13 y Arzam 230); se encuentra en los textos
> desde mediados del s. XVIII, y sobre todo en el XIX. En el s. XX,
> aunque lo emplean Azkue y Orixe, su uso es escaso y bastante menor que
> el de etxekoandre (q.v.).

---

---

**Referencias**

---

El bautismo de urgencia, función tradicional de las matronas.

*Artículo original: investigación histórica.*

- https://www.federacion-matronas.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/vol10n4pag14-19.pdf

---

F. González Ollé, "Navarro", en M. Alvar (d.), Manual de dialectología hispánica. El español de España. Barcelona, Ariel, 1996, 305-316

https://www.academia.edu/36160924/F_Gonz%C3%A1lez_Oll%C3%A9_Navarro_en_M_Alvar_d_Manual_de_dialectolog%C3%ADa_hisp%C3%A1nica_El_espa%C3%B1ol_de_Espa%C3%B1a_Barcelona_Ariel_1996_305_316_

---

etxandre

https://www.euskaltzaindia.eus/index.php?option=com_oehberria&task=sarreraIkusi&Itemid=&lang=es&id=150048

---

- La muerte de los pequeñitos: entre el dogma y las creencias populares. Francia, de finales de la Antigüedad a la Época Moderna», de Isabelle Séguy.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, bien acurado y completa la respuesta. Es una pena que no haya una palabra así en portugués para la traducción, lo que me exigió usar distintas palavras, como "boa ama de casa" o "boa matrona" y "mulher digna de crédito" al invés de "boa chandra" e "mulher chandra de acreditar", lo que me parecería ideal.

Answer (score 2):

En [este documento](https://www.euskaltzaindia.eus/dok/euskera/53035.pdf) se mencionan los términos *Echaiaun*, *echandra*, *chandra*:

> Baraibar dice de echaiaun «expresión del vascuence, el amo de la
> casa», y de echandra «del mismo lenguaje, la mujer o la dueña de la
> casa». Ilarregui repite lo expuesto por aquél; también lo reproduce
> Yanguas, pero añade: «yo creo que en este caso el Fuero habla de
> personas que tenían en cada pueblo el cargo vecinal de velar a los
> difuntos» ...

Es decir, que viene del euskera *[etxe](https://es.glosbe.com/eu/es/etxe) [andra](https://es.glosbe.com/eu/es/andere)* (modernamente *[etxekoandre](https://es.glosbe.com/eu/es/etxekoandre)*), ama de casa.